# Function of "name" in SQL Server LocalDB database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created SQL Server LocalDB database for my desktop application using C# programmaticaly.
This is my code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
...
string connec = "Server=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=SSPI";
string data = "CREATE DATABASE DB1 on (name = 'DB1', filename = 'E:\\A\\DB1.mdf')";
SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand comm;
...
private void T_Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     con = new SqlConnection();
     con.ConnectionString = connec;
     comm = new SqlCommand(data, con);
     con.Open();
     comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
}
...
```

And then i get 2 file (.mdf and .ldf)
The .mdf file size is 2,240KB

Then i try to create second database, and change string of "data" become

```
"CREATE DATABASE DB2 on (name = 'DB1', filename = 'E:\\A\\DB2.mdf')";
```

There is no problem, i can create that file (DB2.mdf)

So, what the function of "name"?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Name` is the logical name of the data file for that database. You can have multiple data files for one database. So, the logical name (`Name`) should be unique for all the datafiles within a database. But you have same logical names on different databases. The scope is local to the database.

[Read MSDN about Create Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx).

Also [Files and Filesgroup Architecture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you sir, nice explanation.
vote up requires 15 reputation, doh
Solved